# Stripping span tag from simple html dom parser

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

HI i dont want to parse the span tag which is a child tag of  from where i am extracting my data.....

```
Ex:- <a class="imp">
     Some data 1 2 3
     <span>
      Unwanted Data
     </span>
     </a>
```

Code i am using:-

```
  foreach($html->find(a.imp) as $value)
   {
          echo $value->innertext;
   }

Output:-
Some data 1 2 3
Unwanted Data...

 Desired output:-
 Some data 1 2 3
```

I really dont knw is there any function or way so that i cant include the child tags ???

Comment: This is a job for XPath. Something along the lines of //a/text()

Comment: But i am using simplehtmldomparser coz it suits my application....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you would have to loop through your first set of results, find all span elements and set each span element's outertext to an empty string, thus removing the entire HTML for that element.

```
foreach($html->find('a.imp') as $value)
{
    foreach($value->find('span') as $e)
    {
        $e->outertext = '';
    }

    echo $value->innertext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple HTML DOM Parser will work:

```
$content = file_get_html($link);
$stuffiwant = $content->find("//a/text()");
var_dump($stuffiwant);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe simple has a clean way to remove elements. In phpquery you can:

```
$doc->find('a.imp span')->remove();
echo $doc->find('a.imp')->text();
```